Part of Exercise 27, XXII from GTM182, blow up of Riccati Equation
This problem arises from Part of Exercise 27, XXII from GTM182. It's a small step which confuses me a lot.

Let $\theta$ be the solution of the following Cauchy problem:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
\theta'=1+(x^2-1)\sin^2(\theta),\\
\theta(0)=\theta_0\in [0,\pi).\end{array}\right.$$
Suppose that $\theta_1(x)$ and $\theta_2(x)$ are solutions of problem above, satisfying that
$0\leqslant \theta_1(0)<\theta_2(0)<\pi,$
set
$$x_i=\inf\{x\in \mathbb R^+\colon \theta_i(x)=\pi\},i=1,2,$$
show that $x_1>x_2$.

I've tried these ways:
1.'Separate' $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ by some functions $g$ and by comparing the $\theta'$s.
However, I could only show that
$\theta_i(0)+x^3<\theta_i(x)<\theta_i(0)+x$ when $0<x\leqslant1$ and $\theta_i(0)+x<\theta_i(x)<\theta_i(0)+x^3$ when $x\geqslant 1$.
When $\theta_i(0)$s are close enough, this path fails.
2.By arguing by contradiction. I want to show that $\theta_1(x)\leqslant \theta_2(x)$ for $0<x<\min\{x_1,x_2\}$. When $0<x<1$, suppose there exists $x_0\in (0,1)$ such that $\theta_1(x_0)=\theta_2(x_0)$,
then $$1<\frac{\theta_1(x_0)-\theta_1(0)}{\theta_2(x_0)-\theta_2(0)}=\frac{\theta_1'(\xi)}{\theta_2'(\xi)}$$ by Cauchy's theorem. Then
$\sin^2(\theta_1(\xi))<\sin^2(\theta_2(\xi))$ shows that $\theta_1(\xi)+\theta_2(\xi)<\pi$ for $\xi\in (0,1)$. By $\theta'>0$ if $\theta_1(0)+\theta_2(0)\geqslant \pi$ then a contradiction is found. But I don't know how to do with the other case.

By (1) I get $\theta(1)=\theta(0)+1$, so $\theta_2(0)+1\geqslant \pi\geqslant \theta_1(0)+1$ is obvious. When $\theta_1(0)+1>\pi$, both $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ reach $\pi$ in $(0,1)$, so by (2) it is obvious. The only case left is when $\theta_2(0)+1<\pi$ and both of them reaches $\pi$ when $x\in (1,+\infty)$. How could I do that?
